# how to determine which JavaScript events are being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, events

As the title says, how can I find what JavaScript events are being triggered as I interact with a webpage?

Comment: Visual Event, http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event . I am sure that that will help half of the people landing on this stackoverflow page :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

when you have firebug installed, the following functions will gather data of all the javascript functions being triggered, and how much time is spent executing them:

```
console.profile([title])
```

> Turns on the JavaScript profiler. The
>   optional argument title would contain
>   the text to be printed in the header
>   of the profile report.

```
console.profileEnd()
```

> Turns off the JavaScript profiler and
>   prints its report.

More info can be found at http://getfirebug.com/console.html

Comment: that profiler is awesome, but it seems to print which functions are executed rather than which events are being triggered (click, mouseover, etc)

Comment: For a simple answer, it may work to just browse to http://www.ckollars.org/browser-events.html and see what messages you get. 

Exactly which events you get sometimes depends on the browser and the browser version; try to avoid "too tight" coding.

Answer (score 4):

[Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/) of firefox is a great piece of software to let you know about that and many other things. Also here are couple of links to help you:

[Debugging JavaScript events with Firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718795/debugging-js-events-with-firebug)

http://www.dustindiaz.com/event-capturing-evil/

Comment: how do you watch events with firebug?

Answer (score 2):

All these posts are useful , firebug of course , and I suggest from personal experience [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/screencast-1-event-delegation-in-jquery/) screen-cast helped me , its called "event delegation in jquery"

Answer (score 1):

Use the Stack Tab in Firebug. Put a debugger somewhere , and in the Script tab , at the right hand side , there are three tabs also . Look at the Stack tab to see the details.