# Is it possible to find JavaScript events that are tied to a specific piece of HTML?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm working with someone else's code, and I want to be able to see what JavaScript they have tied to a particular button on the page.  Is there some way to watch what code is being fired off by clicking the button in FireBug or something?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) a try. It's a bookmarklet that will highlight all Elements in a page with events bound to them and will give you a nice little readout on what's bound to each Element.

Comment: +1, wow, this is a really nice tool, it even tells you what frameworks loaded the code.

Comment: That's very nice.  Now if there were just a way to see where you can find the code -- if it's in an external .js file or if it's inline on the page, etc.

I'm thinking of the way Firebug will show you all the CSS that generated a part of the page including all the styles applied to it, both inline and from external .css files and what lines those rules can be found.