# What exactly is the parameter e (event) and why pass it to JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

Well, when I learned JavaScript, all the books and Internet articles I read showed code passing a parameter `e` to functions that handle JavaScript events, such as the code block below:

```
function myEvent(e) {
    var evtType = e.type
    alert(evtType)
    // displays click, or whatever the event type was
}
```

I've always accepted that as being the way it is, but now I have some questions (this is very confusing to me):

1. Where does this `e` come from? When I look at the entire JavaScript file, `e` does not seem to exist at all.
2. Why pass this parameter `e` to functions? Will functions stop working if I do not pass `e` to them?
3. Consider the code block below. There is an event variable (`e`) passed to an anonymous inner function. Let's say I want to use an event object outside of the anonymous function (maybe in a line above/below the `element.onkeypress` line). How can I do this?

   ```
   element.onkeypress = function(e) {
       if(e.keyCode) {
           element.keyCode = e.keyCode;
       } else {
           element.keyCode = e.charCode;
       }
   };
   ```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The `e` is short for `event`

The simplest way to create an event is to click somewhere on the page.

When you click, a `click` event is triggered. This `event` is actually an object containing information about the action that just happened. In this example's case, the event would have info such as the coordinates of the click (`event.screenX` for example), the element on which you clicked (`event.target`), and much more.

Now, events happen all the time, however you are not interested in all the events that happen. When you **are** interested in some event however, it's when you add an event listener to the element you know will create events[1]. For example you are interested in knowing **when the user clicks on a 'Subscribe' button** and you want to **do something** when this event happens.

In order to do something about this event you bind an **event handler** to the button you are interested in. The way to bind the handler to the element is by doing `element.addEventListener(eventName, handler)`.

`eventName` is a string and it's the name of the event you are interested in, in this case that would be `'click'` (for the "click" event).

The handler is simply a **function** which does something (it's executed) when the event happens. The handler function, by default, when executed **is passed the `event` object** (that was created when the event/action you are interested in happened) **as an argument**.

Defining the `event` as a parameter of your handler function is optional but, sometimes (most times), it is useful for the handler function to know about the event that happened. When you **do** define it **this is the `e` you see in the functions like the ones you mentioned**. Remember, the `event` is just a regular javascript object, with lots of properties on it.

Hope that helped.

For more info read [Creating and Triggering Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

As for your 3rd question, now you should know you cannot do that, because `e` only exists when an event happens. You could have the handler function, which has access to the `e` object when it gets executed, to store it in some global variable and work on that.

[1] That is not exactly correct, but it's simpler to understand. The more correct thing to say there is "add an event listener to the element you know will have events flow through it". See [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-flow) for more information

Answer (score 22):

The parameter `e` that you are asking about is an [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object, and it
represents the event being fired which caused your function to be executed. It doesnt really have to be `e`, you can name it anything you want just like all other function parameters.

1. *Where does this e come from? When I look at the entire javascript file, e 
   does not seem to exist at all.*

You won't be able to find this `e` variable in your javascript file because
it's really not there at all, but comes from the javascript engine executing
your callback function.

When you give a callback function for some event 
(e.g. `element.onkeypress = function(e) { ... }`), you are giving the 
javascript engine a function to execute/call when that event fires, and when 
it executes/calls your callback function it passes along an `Event` object
representing the event that just happened. Javascript could be doing something
like this to call your callback function:

```
var e = new Event();
callbackFunction(e);
```

and that's where the `Event` object `e` comes from.

2. *Why pass this parameter e to functions? Will the function stop working if 
   I do not pass e to it?*

The function will not stop working if you don't have the `e` parameter in it. 
But if you need to access some details about the event that caused your
function to be executed, you are going to need the `e` parameter to get them.

3. *Consider the code block below, there is an event variable(e) passed to an 
   anonymous inner function. Lets say I want to use event object outside of the 
   anonymous function(maybe in a line above/below the element.onkeypress line), 
   how can I do this?*

I dont think you can do this, even if you store it in a variable outside the
scope of your callback function. This is because your function is not executed
right away when you declare it, but instead only when the event is fired 
(e.g. a key is pressed, firing the 'keypress' event).

```
var event;

element.onkeypress = function(e) {
    event = e;
    ...
};

console.log(event); // => undefined
```

The only way this could work is when the code that uses the `event` variable
also gets executed later, specifically after the anonymous function given to
`onkeypress` gets executed. So the code below could work:

```
var event;

element.onkeypress = function(e) {
    event = e;
    ...
};

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(event); // => the event object, if the `keypress` event
                        //    fired before `setTimeout` calls this function
}, 100000); // <= set to very large value so that it gets run way way later
```

Answer (score 5):

When a listener is added using *addEventListener*, the first argument passed to the function is an Event object, so it will be assigned to the *e* parameter (or whatever name is given to the function's first parameter).

Answer (score 5):

I will try my best to explain in the most abstract way possible. The real implementation is probably a lot more complex. Therefore, the names that I am about to use are  hypothetical but they do serve a good purpose for explaining things, I hope ;)

---

Every node in the browser is an implementation of  `EventEmitter` class. This class maintains an object `events` that contains **key:value** pairs of `eventType` (the key) : an Array containing `listener` functions (the value).

The two functions defined in the EventEmitter class are `addEventListener` and `fire`.

```
class EventEmitter {
  constructor(id) {
    this.events = {};
    this.id = id;
  }

  addEventListener(eventType, listener) {
    if (!this.events[eventType]) {
      this.events[eventType] = [];
    }

    this.events[eventType].push(listener);
  }

  fire(eventType, eventProperties) {
    if (this.events[eventType]) {
      this.events[eventType].forEach(listener => listener(eventProperties));
    }
  }
}
```

---

`addEventListener` is used by the programmer to register their desired `listener` functions to be fired upon the execution of their desired `eventType`.

Note that for each distinct `eventType`, there is a distinct array. This array can hold multiple `listener` functions for the same `eventType`.

---

`fire` is invoked by the browser in response to user interactions. The browser knows what kind of interaction has been performed and on what node it has been performed. It uses that knowledge to invoke `fire` on the appropriate node with the appropriate parameters which are `eventType` and `eventProperties`.

`fire` loops through the array associated with the specific eventType. Going through the array, it invokes every `listener` function inside the array  while passing `eventProperties` to it.

This is how  the `listener` functions, registered only with the particular eventType, are invoked once `fire` is called.

---

Following is a demonstration. There are 3 Actors in this demonstration. Programmer, Browser and the User.

```
let button = document.getElementById("myButton"); // Done by the Programmer
let button = new EventEmitter("myButton"); // Done by the Browser somewhere in the background. 


button.addEventListener("click", () =>
  console.log("This is one of the listeners for the click event. But it DOES NOT need the event details.")
); // Done By the Programmer


button.addEventListener("click", e => {
  console.log(
    "This is another listener for the click event! However this DOES need the event details."
  );
  console.log(e);
}); // Done By the Programmer


//User clicks the button


button.fire("click", {
  type: "click",
  clientX: 47,
  clientY: 18,
  bubbles: true,
  manyOthers: "etc"
}); // Done By the Browser in the background
```

After the user clicks on button, Browser invokes `fire` on button passing "click" as an `eventType` and the object holding `eventProperties`. This causes all the registered `listener` functions under "click" `eventType` to be invoked.

As you can see, the Browser **ALWAYS** puts `eventProperties` on fire. As a programmer, you may or may not use those properties in your `listener` functions.

---

Some answers that I found helpful on stackoveflow:

[Where is an event registered with addEventListener stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156096/where-is-an-event-registered-with-addeventlistener-stored)

[Where are Javascript event handlers stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755018/where-are-javascript-event-handlers-stored)

Comment: I think this post deserves to mark as an answer

Answer (score 1):

1. It's just how JS works, you get event object in every event callback. It contains a lot of info about the event.
2. Function will not stop working if you do not pass it, it is optional. Go on and console.log the event (e) and see the event object and its properties. It will be more clear when you see what it has.
3. You can use it outside of that anonymous function by storing it, example:

   ```
   var myEvent;

   element.onkeypress = function(e) {
       myEvent = e;
       if(e.keyCode) {
           element.keyCode = e.keyCode;
       } else {
           element.keyCode = e.charCode;
       }
   };

   console.log(myEvent);
   ```

   but you should know that the event object is relative only to that specific event that happened, and considering that you should decide if you really need to do that.