# How does an event object work in this code

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
window.onload = unblurMonaLisa;

function unblurMonaLisa() {
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = showAnswer;
  } 
};

function showAnswer(eventObj) {
  var image = eventObj.target;
  var name = image.id;
  name = name + ".jpg";
  image.src = name;
};
```

The above code switches a blurred image for an image that is not blurred when said image is clicked. The code works just fine. My questions are about the `eventObj` that is passed to the `showAnswer` function. When is the `eventObj` created in this code? Is the scope of `eventObj` local? If I assigned the `onclick` event to two different variables would that create two `eventObj` and if so how would I access them individually?

Comment: [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) is a native interface, it's not really created by anything, it's just magically there as an object parameter to all events.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: what exactly is parameter e(event) and why pass it to javascript function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936365/javascript-what-exactly-is-parameter-eevent-and-why-pass-it-to-javascript-fun)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When is the "eventObj" created in this code?

When the the event you are interested in happens, in this case a `click`, your callback function is automatically executed by the environment. When the callback function is executed, it is given an `event object` as an argument, which you can choose to ignore it in your function signature. (i.e. your `showAnswer` function could be like this `function showAnswer() {...}`). The `event object` is a regular object that holds information about the event that just happened.

> Is the scope of "eventObj" local?

Yes, it is.

> If I assigned the onclick event to two different variables

You cannot add two different callback functions by using `.onclick`. You should use `addEventListener()` if you want to add multiple callback functions to the same event.

> would that create two "eventObj" and if so how would I access them individually?

The event object that would be created for that event would be just **one**, and it would be passed to all callback functions.

For more info on events read this: **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events**

Also check out the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936365/javascript-what-exactly-is-parameter-eevent-and-why-pass-it-to-javascript-fun/35936912#35936912) question, which is similar

UPDATE:

To answer to your comment:

> the browser creates a unique Event Object every time an event occurs whether we have a handler listening for that event or not?

Correct.

> We can pass this unique object to our handler

Correct again.

> I noticed on your other post they used "e" in place of "eventObj"

You can name it whatever you want in your function. As long as you put something as your function parameter (`function(e) {}` for example) your function will accept the event object.

People usually name that parameter `e`, short for `event`, or `event`, to indicate what kind of thing is this parameter, but you can name it however you want, like any other parameter of any other function.

Comment: Ok so just to clear this up the best I can . . . the browser creates a unique Event Object every time an event occurs whether we have a handler listening for that event or not? We can pass this unique object to our handler with the argument eventObj? I noticed on your other post they used "e" in place of "eventObj" could you tell me what best practice is?

Comment: My comment, was too long, adding it to the answer.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it out.

Comment: Thank you I understand now. I was able to console.log the object that was created thanks to your explanation and it gave me some incredible insight on what I can actually access on a single event. Very Cool! Thanks!

Comment: I'm very happy I helped you!