# Observable with events

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm reading Angular.io guide and in Observables chapter I've encountered this snippet:

**Create with custom fromEvent function**

```
function fromEvent(target, eventName) {
  return new Observable((observer) => {
    const handler = (e) => observer.next(e);

    // Add the event handler to the target
    target.addEventListener(eventName, handler);

    return () => {
      // Detach the event handler from the target
      target.removeEventListener(eventName, handler);
    };
  });
}
```

**Use custom fromEvent function**

```
const ESC_KEY = 27;
const nameInput = document.getElementById('name') as HTMLInputElement;

const subscription = fromEvent(nameInput, 'keydown')
  .subscribe((e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.keyCode === ESC_KEY) {
      nameInput.value = '';
    }
  });
```

I'm know that an Observable is an object that use a function(subscriber) to witch an object with methods to handle values pushing is passed(observer).

But in this example I don't figure out **how variable 'e' is passed** and how execution flow works. Can someone help me to understand it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: what exactly is parameter e(event) and why pass it to javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936365/javascript-what-exactly-is-parameter-eevent-and-why-pass-it-to-javascript-fun)

Answer (score 1):

maybe clearer like this:

```
function fromEvent(target, eventName) {
  return new Observable((observer) => {

    // Add the event handler to the target
    target.addEventListener(eventName, (e) => {
      // when event listener fires, call next on the observer with the event
      // this sends the event to subscribers of the observable
      observer.next(e)
    });

    return () => {
      // clearly this doesn't work anymore as you have no reference to the handler
      // so this creates a memory leak
      // target.removeEventListener(eventName, handler);
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ES6 syntax.

```
// ES6
const handler = (e) => observer.next(e);

// Equals to
const handler = function(e) {
    return observer.next
}
```

`document.addEventListener` accepts the name of the event, and the event itself:

> target.addEventListener(type, listener[, options]);
>
> target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);
>
> target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture, wantsUntrusted  ]); // Gecko/Mozilla only
>
> **type**
>
> > A case-sensitive string representing the event type to listen
> >     for.
>
> **listener**
>
> > The object which receives a notification (an object that
> >     implements the Event interface) when an event of the specified type
> >     occurs. This must be an object implementing the EventListener
> >     interface, or a JavaScript function. See The event listener callback
> >     for details on the callback itself.

You can read more about it in [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter 'e' is called out of scope of this example in a sense. It is the parameter for the function named 'handler'. When 'handler' is used by another function, in this case addEventListener or removeEventListener, it will at that point be supplied with a parameter, which 'e' will represent.