# How do functions decide what is an event value as an input? Ex. (e) -> {...}

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I've see that you can do (e) -> {...} or (event) -> {...} as an input,

But I've also heard you can use any variable for event information like "a", "b", or anything like that. ex. (a) -> {...}

I was under the assumption "e" and "event" were unique, but it sounds like that's not the case from what I've read.

So my question is if I do (a) -> {...} how does the function know "a" contains information about the event? (And why would "a" have information about the event anyway, without being defined or something?)

Thanks,
Will

Comment: Within certain contexts, the first parameter is _by default_ the event object. And it does not matter whether you name it e, ev, event, a, b, someOtherName, etc - it will contain the event-object. Please [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936912/13658816) to read a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

Values are assigned to function arguments, when the function is called, **in order**. The names you give you them inside the function are irrelevant and unknowable to anything outside the function.

```js
const a = (one, two) => console.log(one, two);
const b = (two, one) => console.log(one, two);

a(1,2);
b(1,2);
```

The event object is simply passed as the first argument to the function when it is called.