# Javascript addeventlistener working without parameters

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, keydown, optional-parameters

I was looking for javascript documentation and found this

```
const log = document.getElementById('log');

document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
  log.textContent += ` ${e.code}`;
}
```

I don't understand how logkey function is working in addeventlistener . when I press a key, the console prints its code but logkey is not having any parameters in addeventlistener. How did it print e.code ?

Comment: Event object is passed by `addEventListener`. `logKey` is a callback function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is the parameter e (event) and why pass it to JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936365/what-exactly-is-the-parameter-e-event-and-why-pass-it-to-javascript-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the function as a parameter to the eventListener. The eventListener calls the logKey function with the event as a function parameter.

See in the following example how a parameter is passed on to the function:

```
function func1(function_as_parameter){
  function_as_parameter('Shivam');
}

function helloWordFunction(name){
  console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
}

func1(helloWordFunction); // Hello Shivam!
```