# Clone element with all its events

Tags: javascript, dom-events, clonenode

I'm cloning a textarea in a page but the cloned element doesn't have any event of the primary element, is there any way to clone all events in cloned element?

```
var dupNode = node.cloneNode(deep);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can maybe use `getEventListeners` on nodes? Don't know how the support is, or if it's only supported in the console?

```
function cloneMassive(node) {
    // Clone the node, don't clone the childNodes right now...
    var dupNode = node.cloneNode(false);
    var events = getEventListeners(node);

    for(var p in events) {
        // All events is in an array so iterate that array:
        events[p].forEach(function(ev) {
            // {listener: Function, useCapture: Boolean}
            dupNode.addEventListener(p, ev.listener, ev.useCapture);
        });
    }
    // Also do the same to all childNodes and append them.
    if (node.childNodes.length) {
        [].slice.call(node.childNodes).forEach(function(node) {
            dupNode.appendChild(cloneMassive(node));
        });
    }

    return dupNode;
}
```

---

```
var dupBody = cloneMassive(document.body);
```

But it seems that `getEventListeners` isn't really supported:

[Get event listeners attached to node using addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046741/get-event-listeners-attached-to-node-using-addeventlistener)

---

If you need to copy all event properties on the node as well you will need a list of all, and then simply copy them over:

```
['onclick', 'onmouseover', '...'].forEach(function(method) {
    dupNode[method] = node[method];
});
```

Answer (score -3):

I was solving this problem lately and even that this is old post, just in case somebody is trying to find out, i add my solution :

```
var button = document.createElement("i");
var click = document.createAttribute("onclick");
click.value = "FunctionName(this)";
button.attributes.setNamedItem(click);
```

Instead of using `addEventListener`, just create function `FunctionName`. Well this is useless if you are extending objects that use `addEventListener`

Comment: How does this answer OP's question? What is `startRecorind`? What is `typ`?