# Clone div to have all event like original div

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering why cloned div does not get on click. When the original div is clicked it gets active on click, but clone of same div does not get active after drag and drop.

Is there a way i can add click event listeners to cloned item same as original div.???

Javascript:

I Want to attach event listener to div having id "id3" that is being cloned.
Thanks

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939335/clone-element-with-all-its-events

Comment: it would depend how you are attaching your events as per the above link. can you show us what you have already?

Comment: Provide your code; in vanilla js check the linked answer, in jQuery you can use a deep clone

Comment: I tried using above link and modifying my code, but it does not seem to work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clone(true)`. The `'true'` parameter keeps the events attached to the element being cloned.

Comment: As you can see in above code, i have set cloneNode(true);