# wait on handler registering - selenium

Tags: selenium

There is a html page with button, and my selenium test is testing, that there is an action executed, when the button is clicked.

The problem is, that it looks like the click happens before the javascript is executed - before the handler is bound to the page. The consequence is, that the selenium test will click on the button, but no action happens.

I can solve this problem by repeatedly trying to click and then observe, if the desired action happened (some element is present on page, typically). I'd like to hear that there are some more elegant solutions...

Answer (score 2):

There is no clear way to say "wait until element X has such-and-such handler"; this is a limitation of JavaScript and the DOM (see for example [Get event listeners attached to node using addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046741/) and [jQuery find events handlers registered with an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/)), and for that matter a selenium Expected Condition can't be created, at least not trivially.

I've resorted to `time.sleep(0.5)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some logic to handle this.
I have write a method that will return the `WebElement` and this method will be called three times or you can increase the time and add a null check for `WebElement`
Here is an example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.crowdanalytix.com/#home");
        WebElement webElement = getWebElement(driver, "homekkkkkkkkkkkk");
        int i = 1;
        while (webElement == null && i < 4) {
            webElement = getWebElement(driver, "homessssssssssss");
            System.out.println("calling");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(webElement.getTagName());
        System.out.println("End");
        driver.close();
    }

    public static WebElement getWebElement(WebDriver driver, String id) {
        WebElement myDynamicElement = null;
        try {
            myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
                            .id(id)));
            return myDynamicElement;
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```