# Twitter Bootstrap. Why do modal events work in JQuery but NOT in pure JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

The Twitter Bootstrap modal dialog has a set of events that can be used with callbacks.

Here is an example in jQuery:

```
    $(modalID).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {

        console.log("hidden.bs.modal");
    });
```

However, when I transcribe this method to JS the event **'hidden.bs.modal'** does not work. Using **'click'** does work:

```
    document.querySelector(modalID).addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {

        console.log("hidden.bs.modal");
    }, false);
```

Are these Bootstrap events only useable with jQuery? Why?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The reasoning behind this is because Twitter Bootstrap uses `that.$element.trigger('hidden.bs.modal')`([line 997](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js)) to trigger it's events. In other words it uses [`.trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Now jQuery keeps track of each element's event handlers (all `.on` or `.bind` or `.click` etc) using `._data`. This is because [there isn't any other way to get the event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10030771/543693) that are bound (using `.addEventListener`) to an element. So the trigger method actually just get's the set event listener(s)/handler(s) from `._data(element, 'events')` & `._data(element, 'handle')` as an array and runs each of them.

```
handle = ( jQuery._data( cur, "events" ) || {} )[ event.type ] && jQuery._data( cur, "handle" );
if ( handle ) {
    handle.apply( cur, data );
}
```

([line 4548](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js))

This means that no matter what context is, if an event is bound via `.addEventListener` it will not run using `.trigger`. Here's an example. On load only `jquery` will be logged (triggered by `.trigger`). If you click the `a` element though, both will run.

```
$('a')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){console.log('addlistener');}, false);

$('a').on('click', function(){
    console.log('jquery');
});

$('a').trigger('click');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v4VgG/2/)

Alternatively, you [can trigger an event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490876/543693) on an element in javascript using `fireEvent`(ie) & `dispatchEvent`(non-ie). <strike>I don't necessarily understand or know the reasoning of jQuery's `.trigger` not doing this, but they may or may not have one.</strike> After [a little more research](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11047) I've found that they don't do this because some older browsers only supported 1 event handler per event.

> In general we haven't tried to implement functionality that only works on some browsers (and some events) but not all, since someone will immediately file a bug that it doesn't work right.

Although I do not recommend it, you can get around this with a minimal amount of changes to bootstraps code. You would just have to make sure that the function below is attached **first** (or you will have listeners firing twice).

```
$(modalID).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e, triggered) {
    var event; // The custom event that will be created

    if(!triggered){
        return false;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    if (document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent("hidden.bs.modal", true, true);
    } else {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.eventType = "hidden.bs.modal";
    }

    event.eventName = "hidden.bs.modal";

    if (document.createEvent) {
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
        this.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
    }
});
```

Finally change the Twitter Bootstrap line from above to:

```
that.$element.trigger('hidden.bs.modal', true)
```

This is so you know its being triggered and not the event that you're firing yourself after. Please keep in mind I have not tried this code with the modal. Although it does work fine on the `click` demo below, it may or may not work as expected with the modal.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v4VgG/3/)

Comment: Dude, that was epic. I'm an iOS dev new to JS so my mind is suitably blown. For this project I must use pure JS where possible. What is the pure JS equivalent to you wonderful dissertation? Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

**Native Javascript Solution.** Here is my way of doing it without JQuery.

```
//my code ----------------------------------------
export const ModalHiddenEventListener = (el, fn, owner) => {
    const opts = {
        attributeFilter: ['style']
    },
    mo = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
        for (let mutation of mutations) {
            if (mutation.type === 'attributes' 
            && mutation.attributeName ==='style' 
            && mutation.target.getAttribute('style') === 'display: none;') {
                mo.disconnect();
                fn({
                    owner: owner,
                    element: mutation.target
                });
            }
        }
    });
    mo.observe(el, opts);
};
//your code with Bootstrap modal id='modal'------- 
const el = document.getElementById('modal'),
      onHide = e => {
          console.log(`hidden.bs.modal`); 
      };
ModalHiddenEventListener(el, onHide, this);
```

Compatibility:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I am fully sure that you are a JS Vanilla guru. Congratulations on this solution.