# Bootstrap multiple dropdown menus inside overflow-y hidden parent div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This Question is related to [Bootstrap dropdown clipped by overflow:hidden container, how to change the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829312/bootstrap-dropdown-clipped-by-overflowhidden-container-how-to-change-the-conta) .

The solution provided works fine if there is a single dropdown. but what if multiple dropdowns are listed?

```css
.bs-example,
.bs-example1 {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.bs-example .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
}
.bs-example1 .rates-nav {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="bs-example">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="http://example.com" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown trigger
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
      <li>d</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bs-example1">
  <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline rates-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/y3abqjo9/

How can I make the dropdown visible having the overflow and white-space as it is for it's parent? I tried `position:absolute` for `.rates-nav` but it's not working. I'm using angularjs to populate rates-nav

Answer (score 1):

Here is link of jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/priyanshbhaliya/43tyokm2/

this change

```
  .bs-example1 .rates-nav {
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: `overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: auto;` needed because the div needed to be scrolled horizontally if there are more items.

Comment: @Ravimallya if you   .bs-example1 .rates-nav {
  position:absolute; 
} then menu overflow out div but no horizontal scroll due to position absolute