# displaying dropdown in correct location of modal

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671543/bootstrap-dropdown-hiding-in-modal/48671808?noredirect=1#comment84342450_48671808) about a week ago that was answered, and to what I thought was great. There is a bug with the solution that I came up with.

I have created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1JPQHr?p=preview) to show what is going on with what I'm doing. if anyone could please tell me that would be great.

I added the following code in the dropdown component to do what is being done in the post above.

```
@ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown:ElementRef;

ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (this.dropdown.nativeElement.classList.contains('open')) {
        this.dropdown.nativeElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        this.dropdown.nativeElement.style.offsetTop = this.dropdown.nativeElement.style.top;
        this.dropdown.nativeElement.style.offsetLeft = this.dropdown.nativeElement.style.left;
    } else {
        this.dropdown.nativeElement.style.position = 'relative';
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can't, your container has an overflow property. Either you detach the dropdown from the container (meaning you will have to edit the bootstrap library), or you remove the overflow-y property of your container.

Comment: sounds like removing overflow-y would be easier. how can i do that?

Comment: With `overflow-y: visible` in the container where you have `overflow: auto`

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me. I guess I'll look at modifying bootstrap. thanks for the help.