# Bootstrap Multiselect z-index issue in modal popup

Tags: css, z-index, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap and jquery in ASP.NET MVC application having multiselect bootstrap.

Functionality wise, it is running perfectly fine. However, when I set it inside the modal popup, it is not showing properly, as you can see in the below image.

[image]

z-index is not set properly.

I am looking for any solution such as setting x-index or some other permanent solution.

Comment: You can try to set some height to the `div` which populates the `drop-down` content and then add `overflow-y:scroll`. This will add inner scroll bar to the drop-down.

Comment: @Nik Setting height on div will show some fixed height it is right but the drop-down list still open inside the div of modal popup I want to show opened dropdown list outside the modal popup so the user doesn't have to scroll for hidden options of the drop-down list. As you can see attached screenshot in the question.

Comment: Check if answer to this question helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671543/bootstrap-dropdown-hiding-in-modal?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: setting z-index also not useful