# angular ng-bootstrap dropdown z-index and overflow

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, ng-bootstrap

I am working on a board with columns. the inner items of the column require a bootstrap dropdown. The issue I am having is that the dropdown container is causing an overflow. I need to be able to z-index it above the column container so that it does not overflow. I see in the [github repo](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1012) there is an issue open to have and append to body feature like they have with the popovers and tooltips, but it seems unresolved. Can anyone suggest a solution?

**template:**

```
<div class="board-container">
    <div class="board-column" *ngFor="let column of columns">
        <div class="board-heading">
            {{ column.name }}
            <span class="count">{{ column.items.length }}</span>
        </div>
        <div id="{{ column.id }}"
            class="board-body h-100"
            (onDrop)="onItemDrop($event)"
            droppable>
            <div class="card bg-light-blue mb-2"
                *ngFor="let item of column.items"
                [dragEnabled]="true"
                [dragData]="item"
                draggable>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-title mb-0">
                        <h6>
                            <span class="text-primary">{{ item.contactName }}</span><br>
                            <span class="text-secondary">{{ item.mediaOutletName }}</span>
                        </h6>
                        <div ngbDropdown>
                            <button
                                class="btn btn-transparent"
                                id="columnSelect"
                                ngbDropdownToggle>
                            </button>
                            <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="columnSelect">
                                <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
                                <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 2</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text text-dark">
                        Sent: {{ item.updatedDate | date }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**scss/css for the columns:**

```
app-funnel-grid {
    padding: 0 2rem 2rem;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 100%;
    .board-container {
        align-items: stretch;
        background-color: white;
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 0 .5rem;
        height: 100%;
        .board-column {
            border-right: 1px solid $gray-300;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            max-height: 100%;
            min-width: 260px;
            &:last-of-type {
                border-right: none;
            }
        }
    }
}

.board-heading {
    color: $secondary;
    display: flex;
    padding: .5rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $gray-300;
    .count {
        border: 1px dotted;
        border-radius: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: .85rem;
        margin-left: auto;
        width: 1.5rem;
        height: 1.5rem;
        line-height: 1.5rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
};
.board-body {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: .5rem;
    .card {
        border: none;
        .card-body {
            .card-title {
                display: flex;
                align-items: start;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }
        }
    }
}

.board-body {
    &.drag-over-border {
        .card {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}

.drag-handle {
    cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
    cursor: grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

.drag-handle:active {
    cursor: grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}

.drag-over-border {
    border: $green solid 1px;
}
```

**screen shot of the issue**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `container` and `container-fluid` class on the containing element that is overflowed?

Comment: just tried it, same result!

Comment: height: auto !important;
  overflow: visible !important; from comments in https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7160 and also is this an option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42498168/125981

Comment: I think I am going to have to rethink the UI here. This didn't work either. I need the dropdown to z-index over everything rather than overflowing.

Comment: Yea I observed the `overflow-x/y: auto;` you had in there...interesting problems you have going on.

Comment: Yea, the existing overflows are sort of there for a reason. this is a drag and drop board sort of like you see on trello, jira, bitbucket etc... so the overflows are there to accommodate that. {{ bangs head against her wall }}

Comment: Try changing position to 'bottom-left'