# How to wait until modal body loads before applying querySelector

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog

I am using modal bootstrap to load my component during the click, my problem is I am trying to target the svg inside of the modalbody and add an EventListener to the svg, but it's not loaded when i am trying to apply querySelector. How to wait until it is loaded?

```
 onClick: function(ev){
             this.zone = ev.path[0].className.baseVal
             this.zone = this.zone.substr(0, this.zone.indexOf(' '));
             let dataelement = document.getElementsByClassName(this.zone);

             dataelement[0].setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
             dataelement[0].setAttribute('data-target', '#exampleModal');

             var modalSvg = document.querySelector(".modal-content");

             modalSvg.onload = function(){
               var modalBody = document.querySelector(".modal-body");
               console.log(modalBody)
             }();

             modalSvg.addEventListener('click', this.selectZone)
             // console.log(modalSvg)
             // console.log(modalBody);
             // modalSvg.addEventListener('click', this.selectZone)
         },
         selectZone: function(event){
             // console.log(this)
         }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'shown' event of the Bootstrap modal to bind your event.

Try:

```
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        // your on click event binding here.

        // example of triggering an input.
        $('#myInput').trigger('focus');
    })
```

If you want to use it with pure Vanilla JS you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24211185/twitter-bootstrap-why-do-modal-events-work-in-jquery-but-not-in-pure-js) to see an alternative implementation.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with Vanila JS without using Jquery?