# Find an element that does not have a specific event associated to it

Tags: javascript

Using javascript - How do I find an element in a group of elements that share the same className that does not have a specific event attached to it.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("myInputs");
```

How do I query the result - `items`  to find out which of these elements do not have a `keypressed` event attached to them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution (Edit: This does not work if event has been attached with `addEventListener` as pointed in comment and [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10030771/1977018)):

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("myInputs");
var elementsWithoutKeyPress = Array.prototype.slice
    .call(items)
    .filter(function(item) {
        return !item.onkeypress;
    });
```

Edit (from comment suggestion): `Array.prototype.slice.call` is (more or less) an idiom to call Array methods on non-array containers. And [here you have the documentation of filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: It is not too wise to answer "try this", as it incourages lazy people who just don't want to do their homework. I'd rephrase your (correct) answer that `Array.prototype.slice.call` is (more or less) an idiom to call Array methods on non-array containers and add a link on `.filter` method. Maybe I'd add some ilustrating code, which should not be a copy-paste solution, at least not at this kind of questions. Just don't omit the explanation.

Comment: Jan, I edited the answer, thanks for the suggestions. Julian, you're welcome :).

Comment: This works, but not if the event was attached using `addEventListener`, which is a pretty big potential problem IMO...

Comment: Thanks lonesomeday, you're right, bug demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/uzd2qfLb/ advice added in the answer