# How to remove JavaScript touch event handler from document and window?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, touch, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I have a web page which displays a calendar by [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)

The calendar is being hosted inside a public Salesforce Community page.

I want to be able to create events in the calendar via a mobile device using `touch` and `drag`.

Both Salesforce Communities and FullCalendar support mobile devices.

- [FullCalendar: Browser Testing & Version Compatibility](https://fullcalendar.io/support)
- [Salesforce: Browser Support for Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_communities_browser_support.htm&type=0)

And [FullCalendar has touch support](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/touch)

But when I access the community page using a mobile device I am unable to use the `touch` and `drag` to create a calendar entry.

There are `touch` event handlers created by the Salesforce community page/framework:

- `document` for `touchstart` and `touchend` and `touchcancel`
- `window` for `touchmove`

Which seem to override the FullCalendar `touch` events.

Here is an example calendar for debugging:

- [Example Calendar](https://sfse-developer-edition.eu16.force.com/FullCalendar/s/)

How can I remove the `touch` event handlers on the `document` and `window`?

I've tried adding:

```
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("touchstart: event.preventDefault()");
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("touchend", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("touchend: event.preventDefault()");
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("touchcancel", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("touchcancel: event.preventDefault()");
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("touchmove: event.preventDefault()");
    }, false);
```

But I just got this error in the console:

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.

And none of the calendar buttons worked anymore.

Comment: I found a bug in code that I think you wrote that I expect is the source of your problem (rather than it being event handlers). Please look at my answer and comment and/or update your question.

Comment: You might get a solution on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046741/get-event-listeners-attached-to-node-using-addeventlistener

Comment: @Robs, is my answer not the correct answer for you?

Answer (score 9):

You can not remove the listener if you add new listener. All listeners will be added in the queue. You can see it for example here:

```js
var listenerLoad = function(e){console.log(1)};
window.addEventListener('load', listenerLoad, false);
window.addEventListener('load', listenerLoad, true);
window.addEventListener('load', function(e){console.log(3)}, false);
window.onload = function(e){console.log(4)};
```

But you can remove the listener if you use the appropriate function for this. You have to use the function **[`EventTarget.removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)**. *Read this documentation carefully before.* The parameters have to be the same like in `addEventListener()` by initialization from this events. And the pointers to the listerners should be the same like in `addEventListener()`. For example if <s>you</s> **they** have the pointers to the listerners like:

```
var listenerTouchStart = function(e){/**/},
    listenerTouchEnd = function(e){/**/},
    listenerTouchCancel = function(e){/**/},
    listenerTouchMove = function(e){/**/};
```

then you can delete the listeners like follows:

```
document.removeEventListener('touchstart', listenerTouchStart, false);
document.removeEventListener('touchend', listenerTouchEnd, false);
document.removeEventListener('touchcancel', listenerTouchCancel, false);
window.removeEventListener('touchmove', listenerTouchMove, false);
```

But do not forget that `window.removeEventListener('touchmove', listenerTouchMove, false);` and `window.removeEventListener('touchmove', listenerTouchMove, true);` are not the same. If they add the listener with `false` and you try to remove it with `true` then it will not work. Be careful!

If you want to find the listener function names then you have 3 ways:

1. You can search manually in the code.
2. In the **developer console** in Chrome DevTools(Opera inclusive), Safari Inspector and in Firebug you can type in console **[`getEventListeners(Object);`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#geteventlistenersobject)**. For example for our window in the first example you will have an output like this:

[image]

And if the listener was added with anonymous function then it does not have a name.

3. You can use ListenerTracker script. Here is the source code of it (do not try to execute this snippet – it is only to hide this long code):

```js
// THIS SNIPPET SHOULD NOTHING DO.
// IT IS ONLY TO HIDE THIS LONG CODE

function DO_NOT_COPY_THIS_LINE() //<-DO NOT COPY THIS LINE
{
    //////////////////////////////
    //ListenerTracker Script START
    //////////////////////////////

    var ListenerTracker = new function()
    {
        var is_active=false;
        // listener tracking datas
        var _elements_  =[];
        var _listeners_ =[];
        this.init=function(){
            if(!is_active){//avoid duplicate call
                intercep_events_listeners();
            }
            is_active=true;
        };
        // register individual element an returns its corresponding listeners
        var register_element = function(element){
            if(_elements_.indexOf(element)==-1){
                // NB : split by useCapture to make listener easier to find when removing
                var elt_listeners=[{/*useCapture=false*/},{/*useCapture=true*/}];
                _elements_.push(element);
                _listeners_.push(elt_listeners);
            }
            return _listeners_[_elements_.indexOf(element)];
        };
        var intercep_events_listeners = function(){
            // backup overrided methods
            var _super_={
                "addEventListener"      : HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener,
                "removeEventListener"   : HTMLElement.prototype.removeEventListener
            };

            Element.prototype["addEventListener"] = function(type, listener, useCapture){
                var listeners=register_element(this);
                // add event before to avoid registering if an error is thrown
                _super_["addEventListener"].apply(this,arguments);
                // adapt to 'elt_listeners' index
                useCapture=useCapture?1:0;

                if(!listeners[useCapture][type])listeners[useCapture][type]=[];
                listeners[useCapture][type].push(listener);
            };

            Element.prototype["removeEventListener"] = function(type, listener, useCapture){
                var listeners=register_element(this);
                // add event before to avoid registering if an error is thrown
                _super_["removeEventListener"].apply(this,arguments);
                // adapt to 'elt_listeners' index
                useCapture=useCapture?1:0;
                if(!listeners[useCapture][type])return;
                var lid = listeners[useCapture][type].indexOf(listener);
                if(lid>-1)listeners[useCapture][type].splice(lid,1);
            };

            Element.prototype["getEventListeners"] = function(type){
                var listeners=register_element(this);
                // convert to listener datas list
                var result=[];
                for(var useCapture=0,list;list=listeners[useCapture];useCapture++){
                    if(typeof(type)=="string"){// filtered by type
                        if(list[type]){
                            for(var id in list[type]){
                                result.push({"type":type,"listener":list[type][id],"useCapture":!!useCapture});
                            }
                        }
                    }else{// all
                        for(var _type in list){
                            for(var id in list[_type]){
                                result.push({"type":_type,"listener":list[_type][id],"useCapture":!!useCapture});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return result;
            };
        };
    }();
    ListenerTracker.init();

    //////////////////////////////
    //ListenerTracker Script END
    //////////////////////////////
}
```

I have found this ListenerTracker script **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235801)**. With this script you will get even anonymous listeners, but you have to add it before they add some listeners in the code.

*Good luck!*

Comment: How do I find the names of the listener functions?

Comment: @Robs, please see my updated answer for your question. You can also see the 3 links in the question from the source of ListenerTracker script (see the link in my answer above on the bottom). But in principle all the answers there have not more relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what problem you (the OP) are having. https://sfse-developer-edition.eu16.force.com/FullCalendar/s/ mostly works for me when viewed on an iPad running Safari. I found some bugs (see below), but maybe you are just not touching long enough.

According to the [FullCalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/touch): "On a touch device, for the user to begin drag-n-dropping events, **they must first tap-and-hold on the event in order to “select” it!**" *(emphasis in original)*. You can configure the delay using `longPressDelay`.

Whatever problem you are having, I'd say it's highly unlikely that the best fix involves removing event handlers. More likely you will find the answer in the documentation for SalesForce Community about how to integrate other JavaScript packages into a page.

For example, I found a bug in this bit of code, which Chrome says is from https://sfse-developer-edition.eu16.force.com/FullCalendar/s/components/c/FullCalendar.js
but does not actually seem to come from that URL. Anyway, given the `console.log('loadCalendar')` line, I'm guessing you, the OP, wrote it.

```
 "helper":{
    "loadCalendar":function(component) {
        console.log('loadCalendar');
        var params;
        var self = this;
        var calendar = component.find('calendar').getElement();
        $(calendar).fullCalendar('destroy');
        $(calendar).fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            schedulerLicenseKey: '0537034756-fcs-1530699190',
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            // <snip> bunch of stuff omitted for brevity
            select: function (starts, ends) {
                params.starts = starts.format('x');
                params.ends = ends.format('x');

            },
            // <snip> lots more stuff omitted
```

The problem here is that `params` is never initialized, so `params.starts` is an invalid reference that throws an uncaught `TypeError`. This can probably be solved by replacing `var params;` with `var params = {};` but I can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks, Old Pro. I tried to create a cutback example and left `params` in there. I will remove the update.

Comment: @Robs please let me know when you have updated https://sfse-developer-edition.eu16.force.com/FullCalendar/s/ and I will take another look. Right now I'm still seeing the `params` error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try forwarding the "SFDC" `touch` event to the FullCalendar event

```js
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
    myFullCalendarEvent.OnTouch(event);
}, false);
```

Though generally, I have never tried to remove events like this when I still expect it to work at a lower level... Given you are having problems with your current approach, this is where I would go next..

Comment: Where do I get `myFullCalendarEvent` from?

Comment: i assumed you had an instance of your calendar control available? thats what myFullCalendarEvent is meant to be..

Comment: what methods on the calendar object would I call for `touchend` and `touchcancel` and `touchmove` ?

Answer (score 0):

The EventTarget.removeEventListener() method removes from the EventTarget an event listener previously registered with EventTarget.addEventListener(). The event listener to be removed is identified using a combination of the event type, the event listener function itself, and various optional options that may affect the matching process; see Matching event listeners for removal.

More on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener