# How to get a list of element's event listeners using vanilla JS in 2019

Tags: javascript, listener, dom-events, addeventlistener

There are several other topics looking for the same thing here on Stack Overflow, though none has an answer and most are very, very old.

So, we're a few days from 2019 now, we have ES6 and browsers came a long way. Do we now finally have a solution for that?

Notes:

- No jQuery (no $__data), the solution must work with events bound using `addEventListener` directly
- No devtools solutions no Chrome plugins, no `getEventListeners()` in console. Standard coding.
- No "hacking" `addEventListener()` to register calls.

Is that wishful thinking or browsers finally provide us this info in modern days?

Comment: To my knowledge, we still don't have a native way to achieve this, of course there's libraries and frameworks that'll manage this stuff for you, but natively... I personally don't actually know, so I'll be interested to find out myself...

Comment: If anything like it were possible, we'd probably have seen it on a new answer on an old question by now

Comment: "*No "hacking" `addEventListener()` to register calls*" - unfortunately I think that's still the only way.

Comment: I guess you went through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046741/get-event-listeners-attached-to-node-using-addeventlistener