# Find all elements and attach event-listener

Tags: javascript, html

Right now, I'm using jQuery to find elements and attach event listeners. I don't want to use jQuery anymore.

```
this.$('.my-class').off().on({
   mouseenter : this.handleMouseOverEvent.bind(this),
   mouseleave : this.handelMouseLeaveEvent.bind(this),
   click : this.handelMouseLeaveEvent.bind(this),
});
```

How can I attach event-listeners just with plain Javascript?

Comment: This question shouldn't have been put on hold, it's a good on-topic question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select elements and [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to bind listeners to the events.

Event-listeners can be removed with [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). However, you'll have to remove the listeners manually. Javascript does not track them for you, as jQuery's [`off`](https://api.jquery.com/off/#off-events-selector-handler) does.

Here, the browser support for:

- [querySelectorAll](https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)
- [addEventListener](https://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.my-class')
  .forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', () => element.style.backgroundColor = 'green');
    element.addEventListener('mouseout', () => element.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent');
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bind event handlers</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="my-class">hover me</li>
      <li class="my-class">hover me</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But what about the `off()`. I mean remove event listener. And if you use () => {} an anonymous functional declaration this wont work right.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: @MariSelvan No, anonymous functions won't work. You'll need a reference to the original handler that has been bound in order to be able to remove it again.

Comment: @Codekie is right, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10030771/220060, and here is a work-around (which modifies `Element.prototype` such that `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` mainain an listener list): https://github.com/colxi/getEventListeners/blob/master/src/getEventListeners.js