# How to list all bound events

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events

I wish to use JavaScript to list all events for all DOM nodes, some time after they have been bound. The particular target browser is FireFox, but something cross-browser would be preferred. In addition, I'm hoping for something js-framework-agnostic.

Previous questions do not appear to answer the question comprehensively, with historic questions suggesting FireBug, or a Chrome-specific function call - I would prefer something pure JavaScript.

Failing that, is it possible to hook into event listeners prior to event binds occurring?

Comment: I don't think there's any standard way to do this. Maybe you could monkeypatch the `addEventListener` method.

Comment: But even if you do that, you'll probably need browser-specific code to determine the correct prototype to modify.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235801/476951

Comment: That link doesn't answer my question. That supports addEventListener calls, but not things bound with onClick.