# Using AJAX only for whole website,optimal or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, content-script

I am having a template structure in which there is a single HTML file inside which related HTML & JS files are loaded (using AJAX).

Section are loaded as per User's activity(Page never reloads which kind of is good for user experience).
i.e.

User clicks a menu say "Profile",which causes:

1. **jQuery.load** method is used to load a file "/some/path/profile.html".
2. **jQuery.getScript** is used in **.load()** callback to include js files like "some/path/profile.js",The profile js has event handlers for the profile page along with related business logic.

This happens for each menu item/section of the application like "Profile","Files","Dashboard" etc.

It works fast but I am not sure if this is the optimal way to carry this out.

- If a User consequently clicks the "Profile" button twice,would the browser 
  clear up the earlier loaded resources(profile.html,profile.js) first before 
  loading it afresh?
- When user visit a new section say "Dashboard" after visiting "Profile",would 
  browser again clear out the resources of Profile before loading for 
  Dashboard?

If not than could this cause some memory related issues with the browser?I searched about this but did not see any related scenarios.

[image]

P.S: In this structure often some HTML part is stored in a JS variable to be used further. I read somewhere in SO that it is a bad practice to do so but I was not able to find details regarding it. I assume it should not be a -ve point if the developer is well versed & storing HTML in a JS variable should not be any problem.

Comment: It may seem obvious but by not caching, you do not get the benefit of caching which is OK if those things change a lot but not so much if they remain the same over time.  An alternative would be to change a parameter when the file changes to simulate file versions, but not use a new timestamp every time a item loads.

Comment: Note that "business logic" should all be validated in the back end services whereas "behavior logic" is how the site looks and feels and would not need validation other than to improve the experience such as (check before submit X) but also check in the back end to ensure valid values for example.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I thought not reloading the page would take a better advantage of the browser cache.I added an image for further description,The central content gets updated via AJAX which mostly has table,forms etc but not many images or anything. The central section HTML is stored in a JS variable before updating which once I read was not a good approach but dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding on this:

- You have to make sure that you don't send request if clicking on same button at your end.
- (Forgot about we are dealing with scripts/HTMl) No caching in the picture
- Clearing out resources?, yes it will be removed from DOM if appened in same section. But i guess it's necessary if same placeholder is used for each section content.
- If you know that everytime each section will return same template again, you can create a local cache at client side just like memoization to see if template already exists.

Hope this helps.

Comment: All the dynamic script/HTML being loaded have an appended timestamp with them so they would not be cached.

Comment: Some sections use utility libraries like EXCEL parser etc which are also dynamically loaded in this way.Would those be erased also when a user navigates to another section?Page reload never happens in this app.