# How to list event listeners of the html element in runtime without the dev tools?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

There is this answer: [can I programmatically examine and modify Javascript event handlers on html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436823/can-i-programmatically-examine-and-modify-javascript-event-handlers-on-html-elem) but it doesn't provide the runtime solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any direct API for this, but it can be accessed in a kind of intrusive way.

By overriding `HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener` we can catch added events and store them in an array for example.

```
const listeners = []
const originalAddEventListener = HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener, options) {
    listeners.push({
    element: this,
    type,
    listener,
    options
  })
  // call the original listener with current this and provided arguments
  return originalAddEventListener.call(this, type, listener, options)
}
```

Full snippet with example:

```js
const listeners = []
const originalAddEventListener = HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener, options) {
  listeners.push({
    element: this,
    type,
    listener,
    options
  })
  return originalAddEventListener.call(this, type, listener, options)
}

document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('clicked')
}, false)

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => console.log(listeners))
```

```css
p {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>list listeners</button>
<p>click me</p>
```

Comment: Just perfect fix!