# Is there any similar functions to getEventListeners()

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I know that Google Chrome has the function `getEventListeners()` only available when the Dev Tools are open. I'm actually quite curious, Is there any functions similar to this?

If not, what other options do I have to list out all event listeners in a given element?

---

### What I'm trying to achieve

My goal is to create a function that iterates through all the event listeners in an element and remove it.

Here is how I've been able to do it in the Chrome Dev Tools

```
function removeAllListeners(elementSelector){
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(elementSelector)).forEach(element => {
        const events = getEventListeners(element)
        if (Object.keys(events).length !== 0) {
            var clickEvents = events['click'];
            for (let i = 0; i < clickEvents.length; i++) {
                element.removeEventListener('click', clickEvents[i].listener);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Example Usage:
`removeAllListeners('.myClassName')`

### Why?

I would like to be able to perform the above mentioned task in a `.js` file that's loaded through using the `<script src=""></script>` tag.

Comment: Does your code run in an extension?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski No. It's on the browser in a `.js` file.

Comment: Not a direct solution, but you can look at it https://stackoverflow.com/a/72955413/5089567

Comment: @KonradLinkowski THAT WILL WORK! THANK U! Omg i've been searching for an answer for hours.