# How to trace or debug all available javascript events

Tags: javascript, debugging, event-handling, dom-events

How can I trace all Javascript events of a web page?

Is there a possibility to trace all events, even such without a handler attached?

Is there any tool out there, that can do this?

**Clarification:**

For example:

For a text input I can add an event handler for `onblur` and `onchange`.

If I (in the browser) change the value of the textfield and leave it, both eventhandlers are executed.
Now I would like to know which other events I "have missed" (**the ones which would have been executed if there was an eventhandler attached**).

**Clarification2:**

Can I get a list(on a given element) of all possible events I can attach an eventhandler?

Comment: > ###Similar to: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool)

Comment: This is what I use: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Event-onMethod/CatalogEvent-onMethod.htm

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here is a list of Javascript events:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: This is out of date Please see this: [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Comment: meeech please consider updating the link if you agree with @hipkiss

Answer (score 34):

Here's a simple script to log all available events in the browser's console:

```
var ev = '',
    out = [];
for (ev in window) {
    if (/^on/.test(ev)) { 
        out[out.length] = ev;
    }
}
console.log(out.join(', '));
```

Of course you'll get only the events of the browser you're currently using.

Answer (score 15):

This is my favorite reference, it is updated more frequently than some of the other posts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_event_reference

Comment: True, this list is more up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

You can use FireBug Profiling Tool on FF and Web Developer Tool on IE8 or Developer Tools on WebKit

EDIT:

Just curious though, what do want to do with those events?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version of @simone's answer:

```js
for (var event in window) {
  if (/^on/.test(event)) { 
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```