# For debugging, is there a way to track all types of events in an addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there is a way to wildcard the type of event and then console log the `event type` that is fired in `javascript`'s `addEventListener`

Something like

```
window.addEventListener(*, function(evt){
  console.log(evt.target, evt.type, evt.which);
}, false);
```

I inherited a web project and I'm trying to debug a form event in iOs. The classic "done button event". The way it was built, they want me to capture the "done" click, but it doesn't appear to register as anything. So I will need to rewrite what I was given to make the `focus`/`blur` work correctly, which is probably the best approach either way. But I was just curious about wildcarding the `addEventListener`

**MORE INFO**

1. I want it to be cross browser (hoping to test in iOs Simulator)
2. I don't want to list out all event types, unless I have to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1599216/438992

Comment: If you want to do it in the chrome debugger you can use the Event Listener Breakpoints window on the Sources tab (lets you check the boxes you need)

Comment: @DaveNewton that answer has ways to list all event types, but it doesn't actually fire it on the events. I may be able to use it to bind all of those events...

Comment: @MikeCheel I was hoping to do it in more that just Chrome.

Comment: @JasonLydon That was the point; one you have them, you can bind them. I don't think there's a way to bind on every event w/o enumerating them, although I could be wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah, I ended up enumerating through them all. I'll publish an answer for the next poor sap that comes across this ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up taking part of an answer from @DaveNewton's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1599216/438992) and massaging it. I didn't quite get the solution I wanted, but I figured the answer would help anyone who came across this question.

```
var ev = '',
    out = [];
var logEvent = function(evt){
    console.log(evt.target,evt.type,evt.which);
}
for (ev in window) {
    if (/^on/.test(ev)) { 
        out[out.length] = ev;
    }
}
out.forEach(function(element, index, array){
    window.addEventListener(element.replace("on", ""), logEvent, false);
});
```

Comment: I'm not going to make this the answer right away, in case someone has a better solution.

Comment: This is not bad: as Javascript is not typed, the naming convention is as good as you can get. You could, perhaps, check that the object is a `Function`. There is no programmatically accessible array of events, but here is a full list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events