# How to see which events are being fired in Google Chrome's console?

Tags: javascript, events

How do I see which events are being fired in Google Chrome's console? When I click the button I want to see which events are being fire in Google Chrome's console. How would I do that?

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id = "button" onclick="clickThisButton()">

<script>
function clickThisButton() {
document.getElementById("button").value = "Submitted";
} //end of function clickThisButton()
</script>
```

Comment: do you mean by the event name and type?

Comment: @brk Yeah, I want to see the which functions are being executed.

Comment: You want to see which function is being executed for a specific event? Or, you want a list of all the events being fired?  If you open the console, highlight an element and then click the "Event Listeners" tab on the right, you will see a list of events and current listening functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a [list of all events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599216/how-to-trace-or-debug-all-available-javascript-events), and then attach a listener to each one.

If you want to make sure the listener runs, attach it to the window in the capturing phase, so it won't be stopped via `stopPropagation`:

```js
const frequentEvents = ['animationstart', 'animationend', 'scroll'];

for (const prop in window) {
  if (/^on/.test(prop)) {
    const eventName = prop.slice(2);
    window.addEventListener(
      eventName,
      () => {
        // these events run frequently, logging them will clog the snippet
        if (!frequentEvents.includes(eventName)) {
          console.log('event:', eventName);
        }
      },
      true // capturing phase
    );
  }
}
```

The page may still stop the listener from running if it has its own listener on `window` in the capturing phase and it calls `stopImmediatePropagation`, *and* that listener gets attached before your listener here. To prevent that, make sure your listener gets attached first (like with `@run-at document-start` in a userscript, to ensure your script runs before anything else).

If you also need to see which listeners the page adds to each event, you can monkeypatch `addEventListener` and each `.on-` setter so you can examine the function before it gets added (though this won't detect inline handlers, like in your code)