# Catching the specific Javascript code being executed onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, firebug

I am working on a site that has loads of legacy Javascript and jQuery includes and there is no documentation to show what is happening when.

I have a specific problem to fix and I cannot find the relevant code that is being executed when a button is clicked. To save me from trawling through (and making sense of) hundreds of lines of legacy script, is there a feature, possibly in Firebug, that will identify what script is being executed when I click on a button?

Comment: Wow, 10 minutes, 4 completely different answers, all of which are good things to try. Go team. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug JavaScript/jQuery event bindings with Firebug (or similar tool)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe there is a feature in Firebug's console window called `Profile`. Click profile, click the button, then click profile again. It should give you what all functions were called in that time. Be warned that if this code includes jQuery, you might get a huge long list of functions because jQuery uses tons in its code. Unfortunately, the profiler will also show anonymous functions, which can really be a pain.

Otherwise, do a search in the code for the button's class or ID and go through them. If you have an id of `fancy` then you might do a search for `#fancy` in your code and attempt to find it. That may lead you in a *general* direction, at least.

Comment: That's done it - exactly what I was looking for - even if the output is pretty long! Thanks very much to everyone for your help.

Comment: This really is a great place for developers - I'm very grateful for everyone's time and skill.

Answer (score 7):

You can click Firebug's "Break on next" button (in the Script tab; it looks like a pause button), then push the button that you want to debug.

The next time any JavaScript code executes, Firebug will break into the debugger and show you that line of code.

Comment: Aha, so that's what the pause button does :D I'll have to remember that one

Answer (score 4):

The break button didn't work for me.  Instead I did edit the onclick attribute with FireBug and prepended it with "debugger;" ... then you'll break right there once you click :)

Answer (score 4):

None of the above answers worked for me.  I am trying to use Firebug to figure out how a feature on a page is working for a site I have no control over.  Here is what worked for me.

First, got the id of the element I am clicking on from the page source, and then get a temporary reference to it by creating a watch (under the script tab):

`tmp=document.getElementById("idOfElement")`

Next, I assigned the current onclick value to another temporary variable.

`oldfunc=tmp.onclick`

Next, I defined a new onclick function.  Initially I tried putting `debugger;` as the first thing in the function, but *this does not work!*  So instead, I created an alert:

`tmp.onclick = function() { alert("Ok"); oldfunc() }`

Now, as soon as I click on the button the alert comes up, at which point I then click the "Break on next" button as outlined in another answer to this question.  Then I dismiss the alert and immediately I am in the debugger at the correct place.

In my case, the  "Break on next" button did not work by itself, because there are a lot of other events, just mousing over the page was causing the breakpoint to be hit, preventing me from ever clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebug you can set a breakpoint in some JS and then you get a stack which will let you know the current function call stack. So if you set the breakpoint in function used by several handlers then you can use this to discover exactly which handler you are in.

This probably won't work if you are dealing with AJAX callbacks and the like though.

Comment: Should note that the stack feature is not available in Firebug for Firefox 2 (IIRC).