# How to debug a specific JavaScript click event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-debugger

On yahoo weather page, there is link labelled as `C` that changes temperature unit from `Fahrenheit` to `Celsius`.

[image: Wheater yahoo]

I am looking debug this action and understand what JavaScript gets executed behind the scenes which convert F into C. What is the way of debug such things?

**Link**: http://weather.yahoo.com/?w=2295401

Comment: Let your JS debugger step through the javascript code as it gets executed.

Comment: @GaurishSharma What browser are you trying to use?

Comment: @GaurishSharma: Most browsers these days have debugging tools.  Firefox has Firebug, for example.  Chrome has developer tools, etc.  These are what you'd use to step through JavaScript.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Firefox/Firebug & Chrome

Comment: @David - If you can show me how its done by taking this example, It would be great

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: That's is all built around the YUI library. You should start there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching the specific javascript code being executed onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058103/catching-the-specific-javascript-code-being-executed-onclick)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Using Google Chrome,

1. Right Click on an item which is changing 'visually' when the action you want to debug takes place, and click 'Inspect Element'. In this case we can inspect the temperature value
2. Right Click again on the element from the DOM view and select Break on -> Attributes modifications
3. Now perform the action you want to debug (in this case click the °C item)

[image: Inspect Element]

You will notice that the code will 'Pause' and you can debug code in the debugger

[image: Debugger]

In this case however, the code is compressed/minified so it will be very tough to understand what is actually going on, but the same approach could be used for other similar situations

**Update**:

Watch this Chrome Dev Tools video for lots of useful debugging tips:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaneWEqNcpE

Comment: While this still doesn't answer my question but it provide a starting point which is helpful. Thank you