# how to find out what is disabling a right click on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an area of a site that i'm working on that has right click somehow disabled. I've been trying to find the code that's disabling it with no luck.

these are the things i've searched for

```
oncontextmenu

onselectstart

user-select
```

but none of these are present in the code.

Any ideas on how i can pin point whats stopping the right click?

Comment: do you want to find the code responsible for stopping right click event or a solution to remove its effect?

Comment: Maybe you are listening for an `onmousedown`.

Comment: i want to find the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catching the specific javascript code being executed onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058103/catching-the-specific-javascript-code-being-executed-onclick)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using jquery by this: `$._data( $('.className')[0], 'events' );`
this should return all events bound to your element and using this you will be able to figure out which event is disabling your right click.

Or you can use this firebug extention http://firequery.binaryage.com/ which list all events attached to elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a breakpoint on all the mouse events and see if you get any breakpoints?

If you're in Chrome you can do this by hitting F12 on the page and then on the right-side panel you'll see an Event Listener Breakpoints panel that you can expand. Find Mouse and tick it and it should trap all mouse events. that may help you track what's going on.