# How to find out which JavaScript events fired?

Tags: javascript, events, watir, dom-events, browser-automation

I have a select list:

```
<select id="filter">
  <option value="Open" selected="selected">Open</option>
  <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
</select>
```

When I select `Closed` the page reloads. In this case it shows closed tickets (instead of opened). It works fine when I do it manually.

The problem is that the page does not reload when I select `Closed` with [Watir](http://watir.com/):

```
browser.select_list(:id => "filter").select "Closed"
```

That usually means that some JavaScript event is not fired. I can fire events with Watir:

```
browser.select_list(:id => "filter").fire_event "onclick"
```

but I need to know which event to fire.

Is there a way to find out which events are defined for an element?

Comment: This question lists more tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool

Comment: Visual Event, http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event . I am sure that that will help half of the people landing on this stackoverflow page :)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Looks like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (Firefox add-on) has the answer:

- open Firebug
- right click the element in HTML tab
- click `Log Events`
- enable Console tab
- click Persist in Console tab (otherwise Console tab will clear after the page is reloaded)
- select `Closed` (manually)
- there will be something like this in Console tab:

  ```
  ...
  mousemove clientX=1097, clientY=292
  popupshowing
  mousedown clientX=1097, clientY=292
  focus
  mouseup clientX=1097, clientY=292
  click clientX=1097, clientY=292
  mousemove clientX=1096, clientY=293
  ...
  ```

Source: [Firebug Tip: Log Events](http://haineault.com/blog/74/)

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't know about that Firebug feature. Perhaps I need to actually RTFM some time.

Comment: I did not know about it until a few minutes ago. I was writing the question and found the answer along the way. :)

Comment: Your question looks a lot like mine (self answered, with self-comments).

Comment: Note: No "Log Events" functionality in Chrome's Firebug (Firebug Lite) yet (version 1.4.0.11967)

Comment: A recent blog entry from Firebug's developer: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-tip-log-dom-events/

Comment: Hi, I tried right click on firebug but I can't find the option Log Events, can you please help me how to find this one?

Comment: Hi, Firbug plugin is no more. Then How should I achieve this?Please help me

Answer (score 185):

Just thought I'd add that you can do this in Chrome as well:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (Developer Tools) > Sources> Event Listener Breakpoints (on the right).

You can also view all events that have already been attached by simply right clicking on the element and then browsing its properties (the panel on the right).

For example:

Right click on the upvote button to the left

Select inspect element

Collapse the styles section (section on the far right - double chevron)

Expand the event listeners option

Now you can see the events bound to the upvote

Not sure if it's quite as powerful as the firebug option, but has been enough for most of my stuff.

Another option that is a bit different but surprisingly awesome is Visual Event: 
http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

It highlights all of the elements on a page that have been bound and has popovers showing the functions that are called. Pretty nifty for a bookmark! There's a Chrome plugin as well if that's more your thing - not sure about other browsers.

[AnonymousAndrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608497/anonymousandrew%20%22AnonymousAndrew) has also pointed out [`monitorEvents(window);`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19793663/522859)

Comment: I could not figure out how to see which events fired with either of ways you have suggested.

Comment: Update: it's not `Scripts` inside the Dev tools (or inspector), you have to go into `Sources` and then look at the menu on the right.

Comment: @aledalgrande Thanks, have updated. (For anyone reading, this only applies to the first solution, the second still uses the inspector).

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you picked the upvote button as an example for this ? :P

Comment: @GeorgeDimitriadis haha sprung :P

Answer (score 93):

Regarding Chrome, checkout the monitorEvents() via the command line API.

- Open the console via Menu > Tools > JavaScript Console.
- Enter `monitorEvents(window);`
- View the console flooded with events

  ```
   ...
   mousemove MouseEvent {dataTransfer: ...}
   mouseout MouseEvent {dataTransfer: ...}
   mouseover MouseEvent {dataTransfer: ...}
   change Event {clipboardData: ...}
   ...
  ```

There are other examples in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#monitorevents). I'm guessing this feature was added after the previous answer.

Comment: Nice! In conjunction with jQuery: `monitorEvents($('#element').get())`

Comment: To stop monitoring use `unmonitorEvents(window)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getEventListeners](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#geteventlisteners) in your **Google Chrome developer console**.

> getEventListeners(object) returns the event listeners registered on
>   the specified object.

```
getEventListeners(document.querySelector('option[value=Closed]'));
```

Answer (score 1):

@Himaas -- Firebug has been replaced in favor of Firefox Developer Edition. If you go ahead and install it, you can log events by opening the dev tools (Right Click > Inspect), then select Debugger, and then toward the bottom of the page you should see "Event Listener Breakpoints" with an unchecked checkbox called "Log". Check that checkbox. Now all you have to do is select the events you want logged in the list presented under "Event Listener Breakpoints". From there you will see the selected events logged to the console.

Here is an image to help illustrate:
[image]