# Click at a scrollable data table with watir

Tags: ruby, watir

Is there anyway of marking several different rows in a scrollable data table ?

I know how to mark one row
b.div(:id, "listProductsForm:productList:bc_4_0").click

I just want to simulate the "Ctrl"- button is pressed down

Answer (score 0):

How does your "scrollable data table" looks like? Show us the HTML. I see that you are using div tag to access one element.

You probably need to fire some JavaScript event. See [How to find out which JavaScript events fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787555/how-to-find-out-which-javascript-events-fired)

Answer (score 0):

The chances are good that you will need to use a combination of Watir::IE.send_keys() and the click actions on the document.

Try something like this:

```
@browser.send_keys("{CTRLDOWN}")
@browser.div(:id, "listProductsForm:productList:bc_4_0").click
@browser.div(:id, "listProductsForm:productList:bc_5_0").click
@browser.send_keys("{CTRLUP}")
```

Watir API documentation: http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/classes/Watir/IE.html#M000497

The documentation above links to the specific key commands that can be sent.  I'm pretty sure this will require that you have AutoIt installed.