# Firewatir: button does not click, no error

Tags: watir, firewatir

On a webpage (which I cannot change) I have a link like this:

```
<a class="PSHYPERLINK" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'PRCSDETAIL_BTN$0');" tabindex="94" id="PRCSDETAIL_BTN$0" name="PRCSDETAIL_BTN$0"> Details</a>
```

In my code, I put this:

```
browser.frame(:index, "1" ).link( :text => "Details" ).click
```

What happens is that the link is not clicked, or at least this makes no effect, but I receive no error. The script simply continues. It is interesting that on the same website I am able to click other links, even if they use JavaScript like the one above. Example of link for which FireWatir works:

```
<a class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW" tabindex="32" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow2');">TESTQUERY</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to fire JavaScript event: [How to find out which JavaScript events fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787555/how-to-find-out-which-javascript-events-fired)

Are you sure you are clicking the correct link? Link text is " Details" and you are clicking link with text "Details" (please notice space in front of the first string).

Comment: I think the space in front of " Details" is what caused problems.