# Getting position of item in Watir, using either AutoITX3.Control or pure Watir

Tags: watir, autoit

I use Watir with IE.
On a website, there is a link that, for some reason, it does not work with Watir. The Watir line below causes the screen to flash, while it should download a CSV file.

browser.frame(:id, "ptifrmtgtframe" ).link( :id => 'URL$1' ).click

To replace this command, I used the following AutoIt script, that works:

```
#include <IE.au3>
$oIE = _IEAttach ("Process Monitor")
$oIE = _IEFrameGetCollection ($oIE, 0)
$oLink = _IEGetObjById( $oIE, "URL$1" )
$x = _IEPropertyGet($oLink, "screenx")
$y = _IEPropertyGet($oLink, "screeny")
MouseMove( $x + 100, $y + 5 ) 
MouseClick( "left" )
```

Now, I would like to convert this AutoIt script into Watir.
The biggest problem is, I cannot get the X and Y of the link.
Can you help?

I also checked [this example](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Right+Click+an+Element) but I get the error message:

`I:/watir/abs_pos.rb:47:in '<module:WindowsInput>': uninitialized constant WindowsInput::Win32API (NameError)
        from I:/watir/abs_pos.rb:46:in '<main>'`

I also added `require 'win32ole'` but it did not help.

I use Win 7 x64, IE 8.

Comment: I would focus on why you do not get the file download dialog when you click the link. Maybe your code isn't doing it right, maybe there is a popup blocker, or there even could be a defect in Watir. In any case, if you provide a link to the test site or the html code, I could try it.

Comment: Dave, I cannot post because it is my company's PeopleSoft installation.
However, I noticed that the problem disappeared when I switched to watir-webdriver (the link click works, without code changes) so I won't investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you have to fire a JavaScript event: [How to find out which JavaScript events fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787555/how-to-find-out-which-javascript-events-fired).

And, as Dave said, show us the HTML, or provide a link to the page, if it is public.

Comment: You are probably right, the link is connected to a JavaScript open that loads a page with the file .csv.
However, I noticed that with watir-webdriver the problem disappears, so I won't investigate further.