# Unable to click button - Watir

Tags: watir, browser-automation

The button on a page has the following code:

```
<a onclick="return ValidateAll();" id="btnSignin" tabindex="5" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("btnSignin", "", true, "Login", "", false, true))'>Sign In
```

my code: `ie.button(:id,"btnSignin").click` does not throw any error yet does not click the button

How to make the button click?

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you need to fire JavaScript event. To find out which event should be fired read [How to find out which JavaScript events fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787555/how-to-find-out-which-javascript-events-fired)

Without a lot of experimenting, this could work:

```
browswer.link(:id => "btnSignin").fire_event "onclick"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the one that u have mentioned is not working. This the event that firebug recorded:  mousedown clientX=1129, clientY=320
focus
mouseup clientX=1129, clientY=320
click clientX=1129, clientY=320
DOMActivate
mouseout clientX=1129, clientY=320                                 One of the developers said, its actually an asp control
LLINKBUTTOn
and the onclick handler is an event handler in code behind file
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
so no JS involved here on button click.
Thanks for ur reply

Comment: ASP is server side stuff.  I think your developer is confused between client side and server side.. at the point Watir gets involved we are all on the client side of things.   The code you posted is very specifically calling Javascript, we can all see it right there.  The first thing happening is that there's an event handler looking to execute the javascript ValidateAll() method..  are you perhaps getting some kind of validation error on the form, is there some other value that needs to be properly filled in that isn't getting recognized?  we might need to see more of the page or the form.

Comment: i was unable to find the button by text, won't return anything. so had to fix like this @browser.buttons.each{|b| (b.fire_event "onclick"; break) if b.text=='Proceed to Checkout'}

Answer (score 1):

Your button is a hyperlink, so try this: ie.link(:id, "btnSignin").click

Comment: ur code doesn't throw error..yet the button is actually not clicked...thanks for ur reply though

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a typo in it.

ie.button(:id,"**btnSigin**").click

Should be:

ie.button(:id,"**btnSignin**").click