# how to click on ext JS drop down menu items using watir

Tags: watir

I have the ext js drop down menu as shown in the image.

[image: Ext-JS Dropdown Control]

is there any watir method to click on this button?

its respective HTML code is in the image.[image]

thanks,
Naveen Kandakur

Comment: This appears to just be a duplication of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991154/how-to-click-a-strange-link-looks-like-button-in-watir  and I'd be voting to close it except the image of the control is useful and the image of the HTML seems a bit more readable

Comment: Some googling on class names found me a site that has examples of this control.   http://examples.ext.net/Examples/TabPanel/Basic/TabMenu/

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [How to click a strange link looks like button in watir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991154/how-to-click-a-strange-link-looks-like-button-in-watir)  which appears to the the exact same code, and thus gets the same answer.

for which btw I have code that works on the sample site that appears to be the same control, and is why we constantly ask people if there is a site we can access that has the control on it, because nothing works as well as a real example when you are trying to figure out what makes these custom controls tick.