# How can I select the 6th option in the list?

Tags: ruby, watir

```
<div id="suggestionlist">
<ol id="suggestionroot">
<li id="sugg_1">
<li id="sugg_2">
<li id="sugg_3">
<li id="sugg_4">
<li id="sugg_5">
<li id="sugg_6">
<li id="sugg_7">
<li id="sugg_8">
<li id="sugg_9">
<li id="sugg_10">
```

I have a search look ahead feature which I'm trying to automate. I'm trying to pick the 6th option in the list every time but I just can't seem to locate it! This is the nearest I've got but it's not working..

```
@Browser.div(:id, "suggestionlist").link(:index, 6).click
```

Comment: `@Browser` for a variable name in Ruby? Really?! You should do some reading on Ruby too.

Comment: To even out for all the criticism, this is a good question. You have provided everything I needed to answer.

Comment: Shoot a girl whilst she's down why don't you!

Comment: I am sorry if I was rude. I said it is a good question. I have noticed that you do not have enough HTML and Ruby knowledge. If you need recommendations on what to read, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks I'd appreciate that.. I'm fairly new to automation and have had no training, just learning as I go along

Comment: To start with HTML read http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: To start with Ruby read http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/

Comment: To start with Watir read my book: https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/downloads

Comment: btw, the comments to the answers below would seem to indicate there's more to the HTML than you are showing us (e.g. links inside those list items). It would also be helpful to know what version of Watir you are using

Answer (score 1):

You should do some reading about HTML. `<li>` tag is not link, `<a>` tag is link.

So, to click `<li id="sugg_6">` try this:

```
browser.li(:id => "sugg_6").click
```

To click a link inside the list item (not shown in your HTML but referenced in comments)

```
browser.li(:id => "sugg_6").link.click
```

(that presumes you want to click the first/only link inside the LI, otherwise you might need to specify an index value)

Comment: *not working* is not enough data. What did or did not happen? What did you expect to happen? Maybe all you need to do is fire a javascript event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787555/how-to-find-out-which-javascript-events-fired

Comment: I've fired the event: @Browser.text_field(:name, "searchTerms").fire_event('onkeydown')

Comment: It just skips past that line and continues with the rest of the test, I want it to click the 6th suggestion

Comment: Maybe you need to fire some other event. Take a look at the question I have linked in my previous comment. Can you talk to a developer of the site? They will probably know what needs to happen to click the list item.

Comment: Sorted it! @Browser.div(:id, "suggestionlist").li(:index, 7).link(:index, 1).click

Comment: If your LI items have unique (and predictable) ID values you can skip specifying the div that contains them.  If you are using Watir 2.x or Watir-webdriver, you don't need to specify the index of the link if what you want is the first one within the list item.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to access this element by XPath?

`browser.find_elements_by_xpath("div[@id='suggestionlist'/li[6]").click`