# Watir and text field autocomplete list

Tags: ruby, xpath, watir

I'm trying to select a value from  a textbox that display a list of suggestions when something is typed, I've tried:

```
$browser.li(:xpath, "//div[@id='question1']/div/div[2]/input").select 'Value 1'
$browser.li(:text, /Value/).select
$browser.li(:text, /Value/).click
```

With this one I get the list displayed when I set a string in the text field:

```
$browser.text_field(:name => 'choice').set("Value")
```

and I try to select a value with this one:

```
$browser.li(:text, /Value/).when_present.click
```

but none seems to work, I can manage to make the browser display the list, but I need to select one value from de list. Any idea?

Here's an example of the HTML of the list when it gets displayed:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete" role="listbox">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Value 1</a></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Value 2</a></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Value 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You probably have to fire javascript event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787555/how-to-find-out-which-javascript-events-fired

Comment: just to be clear (since a lot of folks are often confused by this), an LI tag is a "List Item" which is a kind of container element used to hold stuff in an Un-ordered List (UL tag).  Inside those in your HTML above you have 'links' which are A (Anchor) tags. Anchor elements are what create 'hyper-links' in a 'hyper-text' web page, what everyone just calls 'links' for short, everyone except the people who created the HTML specifications that is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try clicking the link instead of the list item?

```
$browser.link(:text, /Value/).when_present.click
```

Comment: Oh god, what the heck I was thinking? I managed to get it with xpath, but that one is much better.