# How to capture DOM events in Firebug?

Tags: events, firebug

Is there a way to see all the DOM events that fire on a page - like onClick and onBlur? I am not finding any way in Firebug to see those.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3787591/245966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click an element in `HTML` tab and choose `Log events` option. If you do it on `<body>` you'll basically see all the events on the page. It will be a flood of events, but you can then turn it off, and use `find` bar in Firebug to filter the events that are interesting to you.

Blog article from Firebug's developer on this:
http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-tip-log-dom-events/