# How do I check if any Javascript event has been fired, anywhere?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, firebug, dom-events

I came across this question:
[How to find out which JavaScript events fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787555/how-to-find-out-which-javascript-events-fired)

But, that method of using Firebug will help me only if I log the events of a particular element right?

Here's my situation:

I want to analyze a webpage. It displays a list of headlines, and after you scroll down at the bottom of the page, something happens and then it fetches the next 20 headlines from the server and adds it back to the page. I would like to know exactly which event is fired and which function is called as this happens. How do I do that?

Comment: Set a XHR breakpoint. In Chrome tools, that would be on the "sources" tab, right pane.

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome or Firefox Developer Tools and check under the networks tab.
For Firebug check console or scripts.
It shows you all the external files that have been used in your page.

Answer (score -3):

Don't forget about

```
console.log("event fired");
```

Comment: This purely logs a string... it is not triggered by any event firing and has absolutely nothing to do with the question.