# Is there a way to track all Javascript events fired in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

It looks like there is [a way to do this in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787555/how-to-find-out-which-javascript-events-fired) but I'm not finding any information about how to do this in Internet Explorer, which needs this more than all as it's a constant problem child for us.

Looking for something more elegant than adding 10,000 `console.log()` statements, which is what I'm doing right now...

Comment: A good tool for IE performance debugging is DynaTrace Ajax edition http://www.compuware.com/en_us/application-performance-management/products/ajax-free-edition.html  Not sure if it does exactly what you are asking for ALL events though

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - I've actually used them for years, but thanks for your response.