# How to detect triggered javascript function?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have a form button on a webpage.  When the button is clicked, it creates a popup box.  I'd like to know where the js function is that triggers the popup.

Does anyone know how to detect that in browser tools?

Comment: Check the button click listeners in the chrome dev tools. If the popup is pre-created and hidden, then you may put a breakpoint on attributes modification of the DOM node.

Comment: This post could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787555/how-to-find-out-which-javascript-events-fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome's developer tools, click on the 'Sources' tab. On the right hand panel, expand the 'Event Listeners' section, open the 'Mouse' section, and select 'Click'. This will set a breakpoint on that event, so when you click the button, it will show you the exact location in the code.

[image]

Comment: There's mousemove and mouseup.  Lots and lots of stuff in those.  There is a click at the root level.  I'm not sure how to set a breakpoint on it though.

Comment: I don't have anything like that.  Not sure how you got there.

Comment: You've selected the 'click' option -- that's correct. Now you simply click on the button on your webpage. The code should break at the correct point. Google's [DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-on-javascript-event-listeners) page might help explain it at bit better.