# How to find which Javascript fires or handles an event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, developer-tools

I am working on a HTML5 application framework, run by a SAP JEE application server, build for companies and their intranet and extranet sites. It is based on the grid framework "[Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/)" and besides that contains a lot of (also third party) Javascript.

I am currently examining a bug, where clicking a specific icon in a menu, when the page is scrolled down, makes the page somehow scroll back again upwards.

Since there is this great amount of Javascript around, I am currently struggling to find the JS code snippet, which is causing this odd behaviour.

I've read [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787555/how-to-find-out-which-javascript-events-fired), and got to know event logging in Firebug and inspecting event handlers in Chrome, but that didn't really help me.

I found out that using:

```
$(<my Elem>).on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

I can prevent the scrolling, but I still didn't discover the cause of it.

Has anybody some more advice on how to find the real cause of this?

Comment: If tracking event handlers doesn't work, you could search for occurrences of `.scrollTop` in your code (this is most probably the property manipulated to change the scroll).

Comment: Are you sure that the behaviour is caused by JavaScript? Things like `<a href="#">` may cause scrolling as well when the click event is not properly handled.

Comment: Bam, that's it! Stupid me, I should've been aware of this. Would you please add your comment as an answer, to let me upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour might be caused by several different reasons. One of them that is often overlooked is links like `<a href="#">Some JavaScript Handler</a>`.

When the JavaScript handler does not properly handle the event (e.g. by calling `event.preventDefault()`, the HTML link will be followed in addition to the JavaScript handler. Most browsers handle a link to an empty anchor tag `#` by going to the top of the page. This can easily be avoided when using an empty `href` attribute like `<a href>Some JavaScript Handler</a>`.