# Can one filter the events that are logged by Firebug?

Tags: jquery, events, firebug, jquery-events

Is it possible to filter which events are logged by the `Log Events` option in Firebug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the search bar towards the top right in the console? Works for me on FF4.

[image: Firebug Console Filter]

See also: [How to debug JavaScript/jQuery event bindings with Firebug (or similar tool)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool/571087#571087)

Comment: That's really useful ngac, do you know if it's possible to filter what is logged, rather than the log results?

Comment: @StuperUser Oops, was that your original question? Sorry if I put in a dumb reply that you already knew of! And AFAIK, there isn't anyway to do that - if it's your own page, you might instead try some sort of a jQuery plugin that logs only select events or events that target selected elements? Also, perhaps some of the plugins/methods suggested in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool/) might be useful starting points.

Comment: Not a dumb answer, since I can't filter, that's going to be really useful. That SO answer is great too. Cheers.