# How can I bind all events on a DOM element?

Tags: jquery, dom-events

How can I bind all events (i.e. `click`, `keypress`, `mousedown`) on a DOM element, using jQuery, without listing each one out individually?

Example:

```
$('#some-el').bind('all events', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
});
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

there is a simple (but not accurate) way to test all events:

```
function getAllEvents(element) {
    var result = [];
    for (var key in element) {
        if (key.indexOf('on') === 0) {
            result.push(key.slice(2));
        }
    }
    return result.join(' ');
}
```

then bind all events like this:

```
var el = $('#some-el');
el.bind(getAllEvents(el[0]), function(e) {
    /* insert your code */
});
```

Comment: Does absolutely nothing for textarea or input type button in Chrome 12 and FF 5.

Comment: @Bobby There was a missing `.slice(2)` - I fixed it.

Comment: This answer is deprecated for new JQuery Versions, use a list of events instead "getAllEvents"  function call: "blur change click contextmenu dblclick error focus focusin focusout keydown keypress keyup load mousedown mouseenter mouseleave mousemove mouseout mouseover mouseup resize scroll select submit unload"

Answer (score 54):

You also can redefine jQuery.event.trigger to catch each event, but, I think, this way is good only for exploring external API, not for production:

```
var oldJQueryEventTrigger = jQuery.event.trigger;
jQuery.event.trigger = function( event, data, elem, onlyHandlers ) { 
  console.log( event, data, elem, onlyHandlers ); 
  oldJQueryEventTrigger( event, data, elem, onlyHandlers ); 
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I was hoping it would do. +1

Answer (score 10):

Here's a small extension for jQuery:

```
$.fn.onAny = function(cb){
  for(var k in this[0])
    if(k.search('on') === 0)
      this.on(k.slice(2), function(e){
        // Probably there's a better way to call a callback function with right context, $.proxy() ?
        cb.apply(this,[e]);
      });
  return this;
};
```

Usage:

```
$('#foo').onAny(function(e){
  console.log(e.type);
});
```

Also you can just use browser console (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18850523/813087)):

```
monitorEvents($0, 'mouse'); // log all events of an inspected element
monitorEvents(document.body); // log all events on the body
monitorEvents(document.body, 'mouse'); // log mouse events on the body
monitorEvents(document.body.querySelectorAll('input')); // log all events on inputs
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to bind multiple events to the same function, simply separate them with spaces.

```
$("#test").bind("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click " +
    "dblclick mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter " + 
     "mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup error", function(e){
    $("#r").empty().text(e.type);
});
```

[**Simple example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/msSy3/)

Comment: "contextmenu" is missing in the list

Answer (score 9):

jQuery changed how it saves events, there's [a couple ways to extract the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/571087/1037948) depending on which version you're using.  I've [encapsulated the "most recent" version in a plugin](https://github.com/zaus/MyJsUtilities/blob/master/jquery-extras.js), but essentially you want:

```
var events = $._data($('yourelement')[0], "events");
```

This gives a nested list of all the bound events, grouped by the "base" event (no namespace).

However, I just realized you want all the native jQuery events - you could inspect `$.event`, which has some of them under `$.event.special`, but the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5848702/1037948) may still be your best bet.  You can also look at what [jQuery lists as possible binding functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think jQuery supports any wildcard (it would be difficult and fraught with peril), but the list of standard events is finite (though sadly a bit spread out across the [DOM2 events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/), the [DOM2 HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/), and the [DOM3 events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/)), you could always simply list them. jQuery does allow you to give multiple event names to bind (space-delimited), e.g.:

```
$('#some-el').bind('click dblclick mouseover mouseout' /* etc.*/,function(e){
    console.log(e.type);
});
```

Comment: Here is a list of all possible events (from jquery source): blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup error contextmenu

Comment: Unfortunately there are browser specific (?) events like 'cut' and 'paste' for example. As well as custom events of course.

Comment: @Armin jQuery seems to not mention the `onwheel` event.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken Mark Coleman's script and enhanced it a bit for my needs.

I would like to share it with you: http://jsfiddle.net/msSy3/65/

```
var lastEvent = null,
    countEvent = 0;
$("#test").bind("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click" + " dblclick mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter " + "mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup error", function (e) {
    if (lastEvent !== e.type) {
        countEvent++;
        $("#r").prepend("<span>" + countEvent + ": " + e.type + "<br></span>");
        $("#r > span:nth-child(21)").remove();
        lastEvent = e.type;
    }
});
```