# jQuery bind all events on object

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How all events of dom element can be bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848598/how-all-events-of-dom-element-can-be-bind)

I have an object that gets events triggered against it.

How do I bind all the events and console.log the event name?

Answer (score 8):

You can bind all the standard javascript events by including them in the bind call separated by spaces.  [The jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) provide this list:

```
blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick mousedown mouseup  mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup error
```

So, to bind the event for click, blur and focus:

```
   $('#foo').bind('click blur focus', function(event) {
      console.log(event.type);
    });
```

If you're looking for custom events, you'll have to look at the API and bind those as well.  There doesn't *appear* to be any way to bind on *any* event.

Comment: I don't think this directly answers the question. Reading between the lines, I can sort of see where you're going, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: @Wylie The jQuery API doesn't provide a way of doing it, and the native javascript way of binding events is with onevent="code" attributes, or through AddEventListener.  I suppose there *could* be a plugin out there somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, turns out this question is an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848598/how-all-events-of-dom-element-can-be-bind  All the accepted answer there is doing is auto-generating the list of javascript events.  It still wouldn't handle custom events.