# How can i catch the firefox spellcheck correction event?

Tags: javascript, firefox, onchange, spell-checking

I have a textarea. After writing some misspelled text and using rightclick -> correction the word gets replaced with a correctly spelled word. 
Now, my problem here is that i need to exectue some javascript code when the correction gets done.

**How can i catch the firefox spellcheck correction event?**
If there is a only a solution using a firefox Add-On i would be happy too to know that one.

Comment: Is it only spell checking you're interested in capturing, or are you trying to capture spell checking corrections in addition to keyboard and other events.  Do you need to differentiate between spell checking corrections and other types of text input?

Comment: in my case i do not need to differentiate between them (but a solution to just the correction would be nicer)

Comment: To clarify (this rather old question, but was linked recently) - this is the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/input_event) *event* which can be set via the `oninput` *property* - if listening for an event, use `.addEventListener("input",`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mozilla fires [oninput](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php) in this case, didn't test in others, but should work everywhere.

Interestingly enough, FF seems to fire *two* input events when using spelling correction: it deletes the word first, and then inserts the new one:

```
> value=[holy coww]
(right click and choose "cow")
> value=[holy ]
> value=[holy cow]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ssYq/

Comment: Just to clarify, `oninput` is supported in Firefox, Chrome, IE 9 (buggy), Opera and Safari, but has bugs or is unsupported in older versions.  However, the OP makes it sound like he needs to differentiate between different types of input, which `oninput` doesn't let you do.

Comment: Unfortunatly, i do not seem to make it work. Maybe it is because i need to apply it to a contenteditable body element which is placed inside an iframe on my page (it is a realtime editor).

Comment: Hmm, you mentioned textarea in your question... Anyways, you can always bind all events to an element in question (using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577346/jquery-bind-all-events-on-object) and look in your console which events are being fired.

Comment: @Thariama: `oninput` doesn't fire for contenteditable elements (in most browsers), unfortunately.

Comment: right, i tried to make it as easy as possible in the question, but in fact it is a bit more complex. that was exactly what i tried - result is nothing

Comment: @AndyE: that's exactly what i feared (and what explains why i am not able to make it fire)

Comment: +1 thanks for your solution, which i will accept due to the fact that it works for the question i asked (but not for my exact use case). looks like there is no approch for exactly that one to be found. I thought of a firefox add-on to catch the correction event, but i have not been able to find anything on the net.

Answer (score 1):

I was originally going to suggest the `oninput` event, like [thg435's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9077826/94197), but I thought I'd fish for more details in the comments first.  If you don't need to differentiate between spell checker corrections and other types of input (keyboard, paste, drag and drop, etc), then `oninput` would do the job just fine.

If you *do* want to differentiate between those types of input, then I'm afraid there's no event that fires specifically for spell checker corrections.  However, there are events for most other types of input, so you could *at least* narrow down the likelihood of your input event being a correction if you check for other types of event first.  Consider the following:

```
(function () {
    var el = document.getElementById("MyInput"),
        ignore = false;

    el.oninput = function (e) {
        // ignore the events that we don't need to capture
        if (ignore) {
            ignore = false;
            return true;
        }

        // Your code here
    }

    // IIRC, you need the following line for the `ondrop` event to fire
    el.ondragover = function () { return false; }

    // Ignore paste, drop and keypress operations
    el.onpaste = el.ondrop = el.onkeypress = setIgnore;

    function setIgnore (e) {
        ignore = true; 
    }
})();
```

This isn't a perfect solution, however. For instance, the event will still fire for Undo/Redo actions (and, perhaps some other actions) that aren't initiated by the keyboard.

Comment: +1 a solution to my question, but does not cover every single case