# jquery detect when user uses browser auto correct

Tags: jquery, forms, textbox

I have a textbox and I have a keyup event wired to it with jquery. Everything works well, except when the user uses their browser's auto correct function.

If a word is corrected, jquery does not register a keyup event (or any other event that I can tell).

How could I go about getting an event called when the textbox is changed by autocorrect?

**Update**

Here is the code snippet that does the work

```
$(function() {

        //two styles of live field
        var style1 = " Youth Congress";
        var style2 = "Youth Congress Of ";

        // #CharterName is the input text
        // #dynamicName is the output span
        function update() {
            if (!$("#rb_NameStyle_Prepend").is(':checked')) {
                $("#dynamicName").html($("#CharterName").val() + style1);
            } else {
                $("#dynamicName").html(style2 + $("#CharterName").val());
            }
        }

        update();

        #These are just radio buttons
        $("#rb_NameStyle_Prepend").change(update);
        $("#rb_NameStyle_Append").change(update);


        // If I can find an event that is called on an autocorrect,
        // I would just add it to the list
        $("#CharterName").keyup(update);
        $("#CharterName").blur(update);
        $("#CharterName").change(update);
    });
```

Comment: it should fire `change`

Comment: nope. Registered for `change`, `blur`, and `keyup` but still nothing

Comment: Please provide code and/or [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077624/how-can-i-catch-the-firefox-spellcheck-correction-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Line!!

I simply wired the update event to

```
document.getElementById("CharterName").oninput = update;
```

and my text updated when the browser updated the input.