# Is it possible to write a jQuery callback for "on-spellcheck-complete"?

Tags: jquery, spell-checking

For an application I recently wrote, user input can sometimes be sizable - over 1 MB for a single textarea. The whole process of paste-then-spellcheck can take over 10 seconds.

I wrote a callback to show a spinning .gif with the message "Processing" as a **paste** callback:

```
$("#TA").on("paste", function () {
    show_spinning_gif();
});
```

This works fine, and the gif appears almost immediately (though it is laggy). However the spellcheck still does not finish for several seconds more, and I need a way to now remove the gif "on-spellcheck-complete" before the user clicks the submit button.

Is there any way to capture the **on-spellcheck-complete** "event"in jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no jQuery spell check event

there's a [plugin](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/jquery-spell-check/) though that provides specific events for this case.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077624/how-can-i-catch-the-firefox-spellcheck-correction-event) also has some discussion on how to implement in firefox