# On Text correction, trigger event. Possible?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have two `textarea` html elements and what I type in one shows in the other.

Is there a javascript event that will fire when the correct word is selected on the screenshot below?

[image: image1]

Comment: Correct word selected in the right-click menu?

Comment: On click of the correct word, trigger event.

Comment: You can't really do that, but what you can do is listen to the change event on the textbox, and if some word has changed from the previous value, you can kinda detect it like that...

Comment: On `contextmenu`, you can save the actual textarea value and set a flag like `contextmenuOpen = true`... Then on `change` if `contextmenuOpen` is true and the prev value is different than the actual value... Something like this would do. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to get this from the event. You can write your own 'logic' to detect any words changes by checking the `change` event.

Small example using the `split()` and `filter()` functions to check the changed word:

```js
function inputChange(event, oldvalue) {

    // Old words
    const old = oldvalue.split(' ');
    
    // Current words
    const curr = event.target.value.split(' ');
    
    // Changed words
    const diff = old.filter(x => !curr.includes(x));
    
    // For each changed word
    for (let changeId in diff) {
    
      // Diff
      console.log('Word changed: ', diff[changeId]);
      
      // Optionally, you can get the same index, so you'll know the new value
      const ind = old.indexOf(diff[changeId]);
      console.log('New value: ', curr[ind]);
    } 
}
```

```css
input { width: 300px; }
```

```html
<input type='textarea' value='Test txt. Correct this: hoube -> house' onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;" onchange="inputChange(event, oldvalue)" />
```

---

- [How can i catch the firefox spellcheck correction event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077624/how-can-i-catch-the-firefox-spellcheck-correction-event)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `contextmenu` and the `change` events toguether like this:

```js
let testElement = document.querySelector("#test");
let contextmenuOpened = false;
let prevValue = "";

testElement.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(){
  contextmenuOpened = true;
  prevValue = this.value;
})

testElement.addEventListener("change", function(){

  if(contextmenuOpened && prevValue !== this.value){
    console.log("Correction made from the contextmenu")
  }
  
  contextmenuOpened = false;
  prevValue = "";
})
```

```html
<textarea id="test">Helllo Worrld!</textarea>
```